# How to not show the scrollbars when ContentSize does not fit the content in Manipulate?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This is an example of what I'd like to do: Do all the display in the control area of Manipulate itself:

```
Manipulate[

 p = Framed@
   Plot[Sin[x],{x, -y, y},ImageSize->300,Background-> White, ImagePadding -> 20];
   {},

 Grid[{
   {Control[{{y, N@Pi/2, "y"}, -Pi, Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]},
   {Dynamic@p}
   }],

 ControlPlacement -> Left,
 Alignment -> Center,
 ImageMargins -> 1,
 FrameMargins -> 1,
 ContentSize -> {0}
 ]
```

The problem is that M adds a scroll bar automatically:

[image]

The help says

```
If ContentSize specifies a content area that does not completely fit 
the contents, then unless specified otherwise with AppearanceElements, 
functions like Manipulate display a resize area, as well as scrollbars 
when necessary.
```

The question is, how to use AppearanceElements to remove this scrollbar?

(I wish sometimes that M help is not so short and brief when explaining something).

In the above, notice it says: `unless specified otherwise with AppearanceElements`,
but I was not able to find out what this means. What does 'otherwise' is
supposed to mean?

The closest I got is by adding `AppearanceElements -> ""` to the above. So the new 
version now becomes

```
Manipulate[
 p = Framed@
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, -y, y}, ImageSize -> 300, Background -> White, 
    ImagePadding -> 20];
 {},
 Grid[{
   {Control[{{y, N@Pi/2, "y"}, -Pi, Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]},
   {Dynamic@p}
   }],

 ControlPlacement -> Left,
 Alignment -> Center,
 ImageMargins -> 1,
 FrameMargins -> 1,
 ContentSize -> {0},
 AppearanceElements -> "" (*added this *)
 ]
```

[image]

But notice that the size is not quite correct to the right still, it should be more tight, 
and I also lost the '+' that used to be there. I have to keep that.

So, I think what I need is just to find what the element name for '+' is, so I can use
the correct `AppearanceElements -> "correctNameHere"` and I am hoping that this
will do the right thing. (I tried "Close" but that did not do it, I lost the '+' as well)

I just could not find what that '+' element name is. Any one knows?

Here are the places to find more information on this:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulator.html

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContentSize.html

So, the question is: How to completely remove the scrollbar effect shown
above, but at the same time keep the '+' in the top right corner.

thanks

**Update 2**

Thanks to the answers below, here is a screen shot of the result.

```
Manipulate[
 p = Framed@
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, -y, y}, ImageSize -> 300, Background -> White, 
    ImagePadding -> 20];
 {}, Grid[{{Control[{{y, N@Pi/2, "y"}, -Pi, Pi, 
      Appearance -> "Labeled"}]}, {Dynamic@p}}], 
 AppearanceElements -> "BookmarksButton", ControlPlacement -> Left, 
 Alignment -> Center, ImageMargins -> 1, FrameMargins -> 1, 
 ContentSize -> {0}, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

I am happy with it. The small white line showing at the top corner seems to
be a side-effect of this. Will have to live it I guess.

Comment: Is there a reason you choose not to display the plot inside `Manipulate`'s control window?

Comment: @yoda, yes, very good reasons. For one example, being now able to position controls right next to the object itself, making the UI easier to use. Consider a simple example: A plot, where one wants to be able to change some options to it. Now, with the Manipulate design the way it is, the controls are all one side, and the plot goes to the other side. It would be much better to be able to have the object and its control variables located 'together', in a group. Being able to have the object itself in the control area, allows me to do that. This becomes more important in more complex UI's.

Comment: 1. What you are doing seems to be causing a breakage with the AppearanceElements option. AppearanceElements->None would typically give you what you want and on toy examples with content in the content area it does. 2. Is this another case where you *must* use Manipulate therefore you must torture it into submission rather than use DynamicModule? 3. The "+" element is called "ManipulateMenu."

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, thanks for the answer. Yes, I am afraid I have to use Manipulate as it is a demo CDF. Would have liked to use Dynamics directly, but not allowed for demo web site. It seems "ManipulateMenu" and "BookmarksButton" both work. But I still see a small white line at the top right corner, I put a screen shot of it in the update above. I am using V 8.04 on windows 7. Thanks again and for Kguler for the help. AppearanceElements help is not good and should be made better and self contained.

Comment: see additional edit below that removed the little white area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 p = Framed@
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, -y, y}, ImageSize -> 300, Background -> White, 
    ImagePadding -> 20];
 {}, Grid[{{Control[{{y, N@Pi/2, "y"}, -Pi, Pi, 
      Appearance -> "Labeled"}]}, {Dynamic@p}}]
 , AppearanceElements -> "ManipulateMenu", ControlPlacement -> Left, 
 Alignment -> Center, ImageMargins -> 1, FrameMargins -> 0, 
 ContentSize -> {0} ]
```

Setting `FrameMargins->0` gets rid of white lines (on a Mac anyway) but still leaves the Frame lines there. `Frame->False` doesn't change this. It appears that Manipulate wants to draw a content area no matter what. The `AppearanceElements` option seems to be incompletely/poorly documented. The following are valid options, though there may be others I do not know of:

```
{"ContentResizeArea", "HideControlsButton", "ManipulateMenu", "SnapshotButton", 
"ResetButton", "UpdateButton", "BookmarksButton", All, None}
```

Comment: I replaced ControlPlacement -> Left in the above, with ControlPlacement -> Center, and on windows, I no longer even see the trace of the white line as before. So I think I will use Center and it should now be all well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`AppearanceElements -> "BookmarksButton"` is what you are looking for. Other `AppearanceElements`for `Manipulate` in the documentation (`ref/Manipulate`) are `{"HideControlsButton", "SnapshotButton", "ResetButton", 
"UpdateButton", All}`

Adding `Paneled->False` as an option to `Manipulate` gets rid of the white frame. By wrapping `Manipulate` with `Panel` you get something that looks like what you need:

```
Manipulate[ p = Framed@Plot[Sin[x], {x, -y, y}, ImageSize -> 300,  
Background -> White, ImagePadding -> 20]; {}, 
Grid[{{Control[{{y, N@Pi/2, "y"}, -Pi, Pi,  
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]}, {Dynamic@p}}], 
AppearanceElements -> "BookmarksButton", ControlPlacement -> Left,  
Alignment -> Center, ImageMargins -> 1, FrameMargins -> 0,  
ContentSize -> {0}, Paneled->False ]//Panel
```